# Path formatting for underscore or non-alphanumerics in URL for YII

Tags: php, yii

I have paths like follwing

```
http://locahost.com/wayinfra/site/wayinfracms?view=about_us
http://locahost.com/wayinfra/site/project?view=justa_hotels
```

I want to use the urls as

```
http://locahost.com/wayinfra/about_us
http://locahost.com/wayinfra/project/justa_hotels
```

Added requirements - When i am using in url manager `'project/<view:\w+>'=>'site/project/'` the url locahost.com/wayinfra/project/justa display perfect but locahost.com/wayinfra/project/justa_hotels generate error unable to find the request.

how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

You first need to configure the Web server so that a URL without the entry script can still be handled by the entry script. For Apache HTTP server, this can be done by turning on the URL rewriting engine and specifying some rewriting rules. We can create the file /wwwroot/blog/.htaccess with the following content. Note that the same content can also be put in the Apache configuration file within the Directory element for /wwwroot/blog.

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Then configure the `'showScriptName'=>false` in the urlManager array.

**Use code below for alphanumerics and underscore in the parameter as required.**

```
 `'project/<view:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+>'=>'site/project/'`
```

Comment: Thanks for comment.When i am using in url manager 'project/<view:\w+>'=>'site/project/' the url locahost.com/wayinfra/project/justa display perfect but locahost.com/wayinfra/project/justa_hotels generate error unable to find the request

Comment: This is because w+ includes just alphabenumerics - try my updated answer and mark it as complete if it works.

Answer (score 2):

Read the following document:

[Yii's URL Management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url)

Comment: Thanks for comment.When i am using in url manager 'project/<view:\w+>'=>'site/project/' the url locahost.com/wayinfra/project/justa display perfect but locahost.com/wayinfra/project/justa_hotels generate error unable to find the request

Comment: You're welcome. This is because you have an underscore(_) in your GET argument which does not match with your rule. (\w does not support under score)